# How to make an expensive function faster in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 application a `user` can click through the *edit* views of his `invoices` using a skip button.

My problem is that each invoice contains the same expensive select box...

```
def self.options
  names = []
  names << [ "Please select...", nil ]
  order(:last_name).includes(:company).with_projects.map do |person|
    names << [ person.name, person.id, :'data-address' => person.invoice_address, :'data-email' => person.email ]
  end
  names
end
```

...and it will be calculated from scratch for each invoice despite being practically the same for all invoices.

Is there a way to *store* these options somewhere so they can get called faster when skipping through the various invoices?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rails cache to do this

```
def self.options
  Rails.cache.fetch('some_key', expires_in: 10.minutes) do
    ['Please select...', nil ] +
    order(:last_name).includes(:company).with_projects.map do |person|
      [ person.name, person.id, :'data-address' => person.invoice_address, :'data-email' => person.email ]
    end
  end
end
```

You can change the `'some_key'` to something unique, and the timeout to something else, when the cache expires rails will regenerate it on the next request, or if you like you can create a task to generate this cache periodically.

Basically this block looks for a cache with the name `'some_key'` and return it, but if the cache key is not found or it's expired it recalcuates the code inside it, caches it and then returns it.

This method is explained in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) and if you're interested, I've written a post about the different options [over here](http://blog.abushady.com/2015/04/02/using_rails_low_level_caching.html)

Answer (score 1):

If all of the data is simply retrieved from the database then consider avoiding the overhead of instantiating objects and just use pluck.

```
def self.options
  names = []
  names << [ "Please select...", nil ]
  order(:last_name).includes(:company).with_projects.pluck(:name, :id, :invoice_address, :email).each do |person|
    names << [ person[0], person[1], :'data-address' => person[2], :'data-email' => [3] ]
  end
  names
end
```

You might also post the queries generated by active record, as you'd hope to be generating a single SELECT with an INNER JOIN to COMPANIES.